# fail2ban failregex pattern format (teamspeak logfile ban added)

Tags: regex, fail2ban

maybe someone can help me with this regex for fail2ban ....

I need to create a failregex to filter lines with this content:

```
2020-09-11 18:44:05.122235|INFO    |VirtualServer |1  |ban added reason='' ip='127.0.0.1' bantime=0 by client 'name'(id:1345)
```

I tried so many regex but i always get this error from fail2ban-regex command :

**ERROR: Unable to compile regular expression '\etc\fail2ban\filter.d\01teamspeak-ban.conf'**

i tried  examples :

```
failregex = /([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])) (?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d).*[|]INFO    [|]VirtualServer [|].*  [|]ban added reason='.*' ip='(<HOST>)' bantime=0 by client '.*[)]/g

failregex = ^([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])) (?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d).*[|]INFO    [|]VirtualServer [|].*  [|]ban added reason='.*' ip='(<HOST>)' bantime=0 by client '.*[)]$
 
failregex = /ban added reason='.*' ip='(<HOST>)' bantime=0 by client '.*'/g

failregex = ^ban added reason='.*' ip='(<HOST>)' bantime=0 by client '.*'$
```

Logfile example :

```
2020-09-10 19:11:00.040440|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |file download from (id:0), '/icon_2496849585' by client 'Nickn4me-1'(id:340)
2020-09-10 19:11:00.044615|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |file download from (id:0), '/icon_237847164' by client 'Nickn4me-1'(id:340)
2020-09-10 19:11:04.259132|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |file download from (id:0), '/icon_428821049' by client 'Nickn4me-1'(id:340)
2020-09-10 19:13:10.717086|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |client disconnected 'Nickn4me-1'(id:340) reason 'reasonmsg=Verlassen'
2020-09-10 19:19:10.804754|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |client connected 'oThername_324'(id:341) from 10.241.207.142:54986
2020-09-10 19:19:10.980756|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |file download from (id:0), '/icon_3456573507' by client 'oThername_324'(id:341)
2020-09-10 19:19:11.217004|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |file download from (id:0), '/icon_237847164' by client 'oThername_324'(id:341)
2020-09-10 19:19:11.230140|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |file download from (id:0), '/icon_2496849585' by client 'oThername_324'(id:341)
2020-09-10 19:43:28.740111|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |client disconnected 'someoneelse02'(id:908) reason 'reasonmsg=Verlassen'
2020-09-10 19:56:26.494598|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |client connected 'Nickn4me-1'(id:340) from 10.201.196.50:43750
2020-09-10 19:58:16.371691|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |client disconnected 'Nickn4me-1'(id:340) reason 'reasonmsg=Verlassen'
2020-09-10 19:58:28.682639|INFO    |VirtualServer |1  |ban added reason='' cluid='RuLfa2hkMrwAz43vVgnOTLOXKruw=' bantime=2678400 by client 'Adminnick'(id:656)
2020-09-10 19:58:28.682973|INFO    |VirtualServer |1  |ban added reason='' ip='10.201.196.50' bantime=2678400 by client 'Adminnick'(id:656)
2020-09-10 20:16:49.381087|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |client disconnected 'oThername_324'(id:341) reason 'reasonmsg=Gute Nacht'
2020-09-10 20:21:23.440568|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |client disconnected 'Adminnick'(id:656) reason 'reasonmsg=cu'
2020-09-10 20:38:46.197539|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |client disconnected 'Member001'(id:779) reason 'reasonmsg=Verlassen'
2020-09-10 21:23:12.803953|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |client connected 'oThername_324'(id:341) from 10.241.207.142:55647
2020-09-10 21:23:31.667814|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |client disconnected 'oThername_324'(id:341) reason 'reasonmsg=Gute Nacht'
2020-09-10 22:17:07.171090|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |client connected 'this-is_aNick.name (:o)'(id:342) from 10.176.87.220:63576
2020-09-10 22:17:13.466953|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |client disconnected 'this-is_aNick.name (:o)'(id:342) reason 'reasonmsg=leaving'
2020-09-10 22:19:14.935197|INFO    |VirtualServerBase|1  |client disconnected 'rMember0034'(id:581) reason 'reasonmsg=Verlassen'
```

Comment: `^\d+-\d+-\d+.*$` how the other lines look like? What is the difference? What specific for the line that you want to catch, is there some word like `ban`?

Comment: i added a logfile exsample    -  yes get lines with  =  ban added ..... ip=.....

Comment: From the log file you need to catch only lines 12 and 13? If that's the case please edit the question and make it clearer.

Comment: in this **short** example from the bigger logfile, yes just line 13 with ip address.

Comment: `^.*ban.*ip=.*$` this will catch only line 13 and similar to it.

Comment: **Thanks** .....     failregex = ^.*ban.*ip='(<HOST>)'.*$   did the trick, **much simpler** as my examples :)

Answer (score 0):

working template in my case :

/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/01teamspeak-permanentban.conf

```
[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf
[Definition]
failregex = ^.*ban.*ip='(<ADDR>)' bantime=0.*
ignoreregex =
```

Thanks to onetwo12